# Plotting CY and LY revenue in same chart

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I am creating two data series for calculating CY and LY revenue by Sales Rep. However, I want to plot both these in a same graph and hence I have to map them by Sales Rep. Also if a rep does not have a LY revenue then it should reflect 0. How can I achieve this?

Controller:

```
  public List<Data> getData() {

    List<Data> datacy = new List<Data>();
    Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;  
    AggregateResult[] result = [SELECT Sales_Rep__c, Sum(Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c) Reve, Sum(Rental_Revenue_Goal__c) Gol FROM User_Stats__C 
    where ((Month__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus1.month()) AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus1.year()))
    OR (Month__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus2.month()) AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus2.year()))
    OR (Month__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus3.month()) AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus3.year())))
    and Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and Sales_Rep__c != null and Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c != null and Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c != 0 and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != 0 group by Sales_Rep__c];
    for(AggregateResult temp1:result)
    {           
    Data opp = new Data((String)temp1.get('Sales_Rep__c'),
                                          (Double)temp1.get('Reve'),
                                          (Double)temp1.get('Gol'));
    datacy.add(opp);
    }
    return datacy;
}

public class Data {
    public String name { get; set; }
    public Decimal data1 { get; set; }
    public Decimal data2 { get; set; }
    public Data(String SalesRep, Decimal Reve, Decimal Gol) {
        this.name = SalesRep;
        this.data1 = Reve/1000;
        this.data2 = Gol/1000;
    }
}

public List<Data2> getData2() {

    List<Data2> dataly = new List<Data2>();
    Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;  
    AggregateResult[] result = [SELECT Sales_Rep__c, Sum(Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c) Reve FROM User_Stats__C 
    where ((Month__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus1.month()) AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus1.year() - 1))
    OR (Month__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus2.month()) AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus2.year() - 1))
    OR (Month__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus3.month()) AND Year__c = : string.valueof(monthMinus3.year() - 1)))
    and Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and Sales_Rep__c != null and Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c != null and Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c != 0 and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != 0 group by Sales_Rep__c];
    for(AggregateResult temp1:result)
    {           
    Data2 opp = new Data2((String)temp1.get('Sales_Rep__c'),
                                          (Double)temp1.get('Reve'));
    dataly.add(opp);
    }
    return dataly;
}

public class Data2 {
    public String name { get; set; }
    public Decimal data1 { get; set; }
    public Data2(String SalesRep, Decimal Reve) {
        this.name = SalesRep;
        this.data1 = Reve/1000;
    }
}
```

My Current VF page shows graph of CY Goals and Revenue. Here I want to include LY revenue also.

```
 <apex:chart height="350" width="600" data="{!data}" resizable="true" background="#FFFFFF">
    <apex:legend position="right"/>
    <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="top" fields="data1" title="Revenue (In $ '000)" grid="true" minimum="0"/>
    <apex:axis type="Category" position="left" fields="name" title="OSR">
        <apex:chartLabel rotate="315"/>
    </apex:axis>
    <apex:barSeries title="Actual,Goals" orientation="horizontal" axis="top" xField="data1,data2" yField="name" stacked="false" colorset="#9ACD32,#1E90FF" groupGutter="10">
        <apex:chartTips height="20" width="120"/>
    </apex:barSeries>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that starts to be a little messy after your comments. Initially (in your question) you wanted to add to existing chart additional bar for **Last Year Revenue**. Later (in comments) you are writing about a table with **Current Year** and **Last Year Revenue**. I sticked to the initial question and here is what I suggest.

First of all, I agree with dphill that you need only 1 wrapper class. It would look like this:

```
public class Data {
    public String name { get; set; }
    public Decimal data1 { get; set; }
    public Decimal data2 { get; set; }
    public Decimal data3 { get; set; }

    public Data(String SalesRep, Decimal Reve, Decimal Gol, Decimal lastYearRevenue) {
        this.name = SalesRep;
        this.data1 = Reve/1000;
        this.data2 = Gol/1000;
        this.data3 = lastYearRevenue/1000;
    }
}
```

Secondly, I would leave just one method for getting chart data, and create over there a `Map<Sales Rep, Data>` instead of two method and two lists. This will tie Sales Rep name to all the values that we want to display on chart.

```
public List<Data> getData() {
    Map<String, Data> repToData = new Map<String, Data>();
    Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;  
    AggregateResult[] result = [
        SELECT Sales_Rep__c, Sum(Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c) Reve, Sum(Rental_Revenue_Goal__c) Gol
        FROM User_Stats__c
        WHERE ((Month__c = : String.valueof(monthMinus1.month()) 
                    AND Year__c = : String.valueof(monthMinus1.year()))
                OR (Month__c = : String.valueof(monthMinus2.month()) 
                    AND Year__c = : String.valueof(monthMinus2.year()))
                OR (Month__c = : String.valueof(monthMinus3.month()) 
                    AND Year__c = : String.valueof(monthMinus3.year())))
            AND Region__c =: regnInt 
            AND District__c =: dist
            AND Sales_Rep__c != null
            AND Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c != null
            AND Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c != 0
            AND Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null
            AND Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != 0 
        GROUP BY Sales_Rep__c
    ];
    for(AggregateResult temp1:result) {
        Data opp = new Data((String)temp1.get('Sales_Rep__c'),
                (Decimal)temp1.get('Reve'),
                (Decimal)temp1.get('Gol'),
                0);
        repToData.put((String)temp1.get('Sales_Rep__c'), opp);
    }

    result = [
        SELECT Sales_Rep__c, Sum(Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c) Reve, Sum(Rental_Revenue_Goal__c) Gol
        FROM User_Stats__c
        WHERE ((Month__c = : String.valueof(monthMinus1.month()) 
                    AND Year__c = : String.valueof(monthMinus1.year()))
                OR (Month__c = : String.valueof(monthMinus2.month()) 
                    AND Year__c = : String.valueof(monthMinus2.year()))
                OR (Month__c = : String.valueof(monthMinus3.month()) 
                    AND Year__c = : String.valueof(monthMinus3.year())))
            AND Region__c =: regnInt 
            AND District__c =: dist
            AND Sales_Rep__c != null
            AND Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c != null
            AND Total_Rental_Revenue_Actual__c != 0
            AND Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null
            AND Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != 0 
        GROUP BY Sales_Rep__c
    ];
    for(AggregateResult temp1:result) {
        if (!repToData.containsKey((String) temp1.get('Sales_Rep__c'))) {
            Data opp = new Data((String)temp1.get('Sales_Rep__c'),
                0,
                0,
                (Decimal)temp1.get('Reve'));
            repToData.put((String) temp1.get('Sales_Rep__c'), opp);
        } else {
            repToData.get((String) temp1.get('Sales_Rep__c')).data3 = (Double)temp1.get('Reve');
        }
    }
    return repToData.values();
}
```

Most of this code is your's and I merged those method and added map but I would still suggest you to improve it: you can merge those queries into 1 and I don't know why you're passing Double parameters to a Decimal constructor (I changed it to Decimal).

And the final piece is your chart on VF page:

```
<apex:chart height="350" width="600" data="{!data}" resizable="true" background="#FFFFFF">
    <apex:legend position="right"/>
    <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="top" fields="data1,data2,data3" title="Revenue (In $ '000)" grid="true" minimum="0"/>
    <apex:axis type="Category" position="left" fields="name" title="OSR">
        <apex:chartLabel rotate="315"/>
    </apex:axis>
    <apex:barSeries title="Actual,Goals,LastYear" orientation="horizontal" axis="top" xField="data1,data2,data3" yField="name" stacked="false" colorset="#9ACD32,#1E90FF,#DACD32" groupGutter="10">
        <apex:chartTips height="20" width="120"/>
    </apex:barSeries>
</apex:chart>
```

And the result for me (I don't have such objects and data in my org so I just hardcoded some values in get method) are as follows:

[image: Chart]

Comment: Thanks @neff this works perfectly fine!! I am very new to the environment and hence I know the code might not be the optimum one. One small thing though.. I am getting CY and LY revenue correctly. In your code I am referring to `data1` as CY Revenue and `data3` as LY revenue. But in the chart I also want to plot the ratio of them along with both revenues. The revenues are plotting correctly but when I am taking the ratio, it always takes `data3` as 0. Here is my code: `If (data3 != 0){
        this.data4 = (data1 / data3) - 1;
        }
        else {
        this.data4 = 0;
        }`

Comment: Hi Robin! Glad to here that it works. Please, tell me where you have added this code for ratio? Is it in `Data` constructor?

Comment: yes.. right below `this.data3 = lastYearRevenue/1000;`

Comment: Ok, so that's the issue... when a constructor is called `data3` is always 0 (we're filling this value later, after 2nd query). So I would move your code to the `data3` setter: `public Decimal data3 { get; set {data3 = value; if (data3 != 0) { (data1 / data3) - 1; } else { data4 = 0 } } }`

Comment: Wow...thanks...you have been a savior.. cheers.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I sort of think I know what you are saying now.  I can't give you the exact code because it would take me at least an hour or more of time I don't have as a refresher on the apex:charts.  You should only need 1 Wrapper subclass in order to accomplish this instead of the two you have. (doesn't hurt to have another as long as the column values are the same name).  Basically, have two lists, one for last year and one for current year for each rep.  (If there is no value for last year for a rep, it will not show up unless you manually loop through and create 0 values for them.  You can do this by creating a Map of the opposing year by RepName and looping through them to make sure they contain all of the same keys.)   Then you will have two separate  on your page, but they will pair the rep next to each other as long as they have the same value.  That way you can see the differences in the year easily.  I hope that makes sense and I'm sorry I didn't have the time to actually dig through the code myself, but I do finally understand what you are talking about.

Old Response that I gave earlier below:

```
String rep = (String)temp1.get('Sales_Rep__c');
Double reve = temp1.get('Reve') == null ? 0 : (Double) temp1.get('Reve');
Double gol = Temp1.get('Gol') == null ? 0 : (Double) temp1.get('Gol');
data1.add(new Data(rep, reve, gol));
```

Comment: dphil thanks for replying. What I want is to create a table which would simultaneously display current year and previous year revenue. I have them as separate tables in my controller code right now. How do I map them using the Sales Rep?

Comment: Ok, so use the same table, but change the name.  So like:
String rep = (String) temp1.get('Sales_Rep__c') + yearName;  Basically, just add in the year as part of the Name.  So the rep name doesn't change, but it has a year appended after it so you can see the difference, and then the data you pass in will need to be different per year.

Comment: if the rep name is different then I would not be able to plot both CY revenue and LY revenue against the same rep right?

Comment: basically I want 2 bars against each rep. one for CY and one for LY

Comment: I changed my response.  I understand what you are saying.  Basically have two Lists of the same Wrapper object, but 1 list for current year and the other list for last year.  Put them in Separate <apex:barSeries> on the same chart and as long as they have the same repName, it will place them next to each other.